# implementing addition operator for std::vector with type checking

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, stdvector

This is my implementation of `+ operator` for `std::vector<T>`.

```
//+ operator overloading
template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    if(v1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        throw std::exception("Two vector size must be same");
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        v1[i] += v2[i];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

it works fine and size exception also works well in the following code.

```
//main function 1
std::vector<double> a,b,c;

a.assign(4,2);
b.assign(4,5);

try{
    c = a+b;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout<<e.what();
    return -1;
}
```

But I want to add kind of type checking to implementation so that this `+` operation will be invoked only about `numerical types`(eg. int, double...).

So when I try `+` operation about `std::vector<std::string>`, an exception should be occurred.

But current implementation does not.

```
//main function 2
std::vector<std::string> a,b,c;

a.assign(4,"this");
b.assign(4,"is awesome!");

try{
    c = a+b;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout<<e.what();
    return -1;
}
```

Is there any way?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you want a `std::valarray` for what the operation is actually doing.

Comment: Anyway, see [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: why do you want to impose an artificial limit inside a function? your code currently works with anything with `operator+=` defined. If anything, i think you should make the code more generic by allowing it to work with different typed vectors. the limitation of just numeric types can come in a different code section...

Comment: @chris. enable_if is new to me. thanks. I'll read about it.

Comment: Why would you want a runtime exception for this o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> But I want to add kind of type checking to implementation so that this `+` operation will be invoked only about numerical types(eg. `int`, `double`...).

You can add a `static_assert`.

```
template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
   static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Need arithmetic type");
```

Comment: @Sahu, thanks. but my code cannot compile it with this error `error C2338: Need arithmetic type`. I'm using VS 2010.

Comment: @JaeJunLee: That is the static_assert failing because you passed in a non-arithmetic type. The trait could be buggy in VS2010 fairly easily I guess, so you may need to replace it.

Comment: @JaeJunLEE, if we are to go by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983022(v=vs.100).aspx, `std::is_arithmetic` should work with VS 2010.

Comment: @Sahu, Sorry I didn't know about `static_assertive`. It was compile time solution! Thanks. So the answer has no problem.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a case for straightforward application of type traits:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    if(v1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        throw std::exception("Two vector size must be same");
    }

    if (!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)
    {
        throw std::exception("Only arithmetic vectors supported");
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        v1[i] += v2[i];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

Since "being arithmetic" is a compile-time property of the type, you can go further and use a static assertion instead of an exception to get a compile-time error instead of a runtime one:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> 
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Our vector operator + is intended for arithmetic types only");

    if(v1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        throw std::exception("Two vector size must be same");
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        v1[i] += v2[i];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

However, as @chris correctly points out in comments: if you want dynamically-sized numeric arrays, you might want to take a look at [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Comment: This would fail at runtime for cases that could easily be caught at compiletime. Also, everybody hates `valarray` because it's crap.

Comment: @Puppy Compile-time case already added. If `valarray` is so bad, why was it not deprecated, then?

Comment: Fairly, I did not notice your extra static assertion case. Also, the Committee doesn't deprecate *lots* of terrible things, like `new`.

Comment: @puppy have a link explaining how it is crap?  Does it allocate too much?